# How to run a SQL select query in Oracle database through a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, database, sql

I need to run a SQL `select` query in an Oracle database and have to capture the list of retrieved records in a shell script. Also I would like to modify the query for certain conditions and need to fetch it again. How can I do this?

Is there a way to have a persistent connection to an Oracle database using a shell script?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

DatabaseconnectStr=user/password@ALIAS
Dynamic=DynamicContent

sqlplus -S ${DatabaseconnectStr} << EOF

spool results.out
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE COLUMN = ${Dynamic} ;
spool off
exit;
EOF
```

Comment: Anyone who uses this, please make sure the folder you're placing the script in is only readable by you. Alternatively, put the password in another file in a protected folder and include it in the script. Still, I wouldn't do this in production.

Comment: A way to get around that issue is having a tool like Jenkins call the script and store the passwords there so that it's not visible to others unless granted.